# Make address to latitude longitude ti.map

Tags: google-maps, titanium, apple-maps

I am using [Ti.map](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Modules.Map) module.

Now I would like to change address to latitude and longitude to 
set the annotation pin.

Like when you type the address in google map serach box

I think it is very simple function though I can't find the way to do this in Ti.map document??

Could someone help me??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Google API to do this :

```
var v = encodeURIComponent("YOUR ADDRESS HERE");

var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
    xhr.autoEncodeUrl = false;

   xhr.onload = function(e){

      if (xhr.status == 200 ){

          if(xhr.readyState == 4){

              var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

          }

      }

  };

xhr.onerror = function(e){};

var url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+v+'&sensor=false';
xhr.open('GET', url, true);
xhr.send();
```

And if you want the address from your latitude / longitude, you can use `Ti.Geolocation.reverseGeocoder()` method : http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Geolocation-method-reverseGeocoder

Comment: It changes your latitude/longitude into address. What I want to do is to change address into latitude/longitude. However I am surprised that Ti.geolocation has this function. Somehow Ti.Geolocation can access the address database.

Comment: Thank you @Thomas, It works like a charm.And This simple google API doesn't require Authentification. It's good.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the built in GeoLocation services?  http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Geolocation

Look at the forwardGeocoder method.
http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Geolocation-method-forwardGeocoder

Comment: Thank you very much, it is good suggestion, I just wonder how it resolves the address , it accesses google database or something ? Anyway I will test.